# Why is Attachment.ParentId read only?

Tags: attachment

I'm trying to understand the reason for why is the `ParentId` field of the `Attachment` object is not editable after creating the object.

Is this something that's going to change in the near future?

Comment: Attachments and their parents are related using what is called a non-reparentable master-detail relationship. Once an attachment (detail) is linked to an object (parent), it cannot be reparented to another object. I think it's not likely to change in the near future. If you really want to reparent it, the only way to do so it to clone the attachment, set the parent to the new one and delete the original attachment.

Comment: Thanks @Lex for the detailed response. My question is why did Salesforce choose to implement this specific kind of relationship for attachments? Are there any advantages to the users?

Comment: As for the reason why Salesforce did this; like with many design decisions they made, I really don't know, but I share your curiosity.

Comment: Perhaps to help put this in context, it was only about a year and a half ago (at most) that SF gave Orgs/Developers the option to not have child records automatically deleted when a M-D relationship was broken (as I recall, this had to be set at time of creation, but I could be mistaken). At that time, the option was finally given to retain child Object records when the M-D was broken so they could be re-parented to another Master Object if desired. Prior to that, all child object records would have automatically been deleted when the M-D relationship was broken.

Comment: I'd imagine that having a non-reparentable master-detail has sharing implications (e.g. less work for the system if you can't reparent a record). Beyond that, I'm kind of amazed at half the stuff they do-- it seems entirely arbitrary.

Comment: for workarounds - see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16129/how-to-updating-parentid-on-attachments-salesforce